# Почему при перезаписи списка он не меняется в кортеже?

Tags: python, кортежи

Есть кортеж

```
kort = (1, [2, 3], 4)
```

Как можно поменять список, который лежит в нём?

```
a = [1, 2]
kort = (1, a, 4)
print(kort)

a = [5, 6]
print(kort)
```

При выполнении такого кода кортеж не меняется

А при таком меняется. Почему так происходит?

```
a = [1, 2]
kort = (1, a, 4)
print(kort)

a.append(5)
print(kort)
```

Comment: Да, можно. Что мешает проверить самостоятельно?)

Comment: @insolor, подскажите как это можно сделать

Comment: Как обычно, через запись по индексу: `kort[1][0] = 4`, или через вызов метода списка: `kort[1].append(4)`

Comment: По вашему коду: в списке хранится не переменная, а объект. Если вы перезаписываете в переменную новый объект, объект в списке не меняется. Если вы мутируете объект (например, добавляете элементы в список), то список и в кортеже поменяется.

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё понятно

Comment: А ещё можно так поменять непосредственно весь список в кортеже: `kort[1][:] = [5, 6]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В списке хранится не переменная, а объект. Если вы перезаписываете в переменную новый объект (фактически присваиваете ей ссылку на другой объект), объект в списке не меняется, потому что он уже не имеет связи с этой переменной. Если вы мутируете объект (например, добавляете элементы в список), то список и в кортеже поменяется.

Поменять можно через запись в список по индексу:

```
kort[1][0] = 4
```

или через вызов метода списка:

```
kort[1].append(4)
```

непосредственно весь список в кортеже:

```
kort[1][:] = [5, 6]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо